# Geoserver returns null

Tags: geoserver, wms, heat-map

We have a geoserver 2.7.1 running as a war on tomcat7 in a Ubuntu 14.04 box. When asking for a WMS we get a java.lang.NullPointerException, but only when the map window is above certain size and only on a specific Geoserver layer.

A request like this works fine:

http://192.168.11.50:8080/geoserver/wms?idx=117&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=true&tiled=false&STYLES&LAYERS=openrtls%3Atagpulse&TIME=2015-10-01T23%3A56%3A31.000Z%2F2015-10-01T23%3A56%3A31.000Z&cql_filter=(tag%3D%27354805064174992%27)&idx=117&SRS=EPSG%3A3857&WIDTH=1772&HEIGHT=1762&BBOX=240912.34468172558%2C5070200.20875346%2C241044.61657051594%2C5070331.734186896

A request like this also works fine:

http://192.168.11.50:8080/geoserver/openrtls/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=true&TIME=2014-07-16T16%3A00%3A00.000Z%2F2016-07-16&tiled=false&STYLES&LAYERS=openrtls%3Apresence&CQL_FILTER=floor%3D35&SRS=EPSG%3A3857&WIDTH=1527&HEIGHT=1511&BBOX=240921.48875981633%2C5070209.576768157%2C241035.47249242518%2C5070322.366172199

But this request brings back an xml with a nullPointerException:

http://192.168.11.50:8080/geoserver/openrtls/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=true&TIME=2014-07-16T16%3A00%3A00.000Z%2F2016-07-16&tiled=false&STYLES&LAYERS=openrtls%3Apresence&CQL_FILTER=floor%3D35&SRS=EPSG%3A3857&WIDTH=1772&HEIGHT=1762&BBOX=240952.01878380912%2C5070235.180186812%2C241018.15472820433%2C5070300.94290353

This layer is using a transformation style to produce a Heatmap. That, and the fact that only changing the size of the image requested makes it crash, would make me think about memory issues. But I have upped the max rendering memory of the WMS in Geoserver to 1048576 with the same results.

Also, if I ask for a tiled image I get no error, but the tiling of a heatmap layer does not produce good results.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

The geoserver log of the failing request says:

2015-10-15 10:09:06,299 INFO [geoserver.wms] - 
Request: getServiceInfo
2015-10-15 10:09:07,100 INFO [geoserver.wms] - 
Request: getMap
    Width = 1772
    Height = 1762
    MaxFeatures = null
    Crs = PROJCS["WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator", 
  GEOGCS["WGS 84", 
    DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984", 
      SPHEROID["WGS 84", 6378137.0, 298.257223563, AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]], 
      AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]], 
    PRIMEM["Greenwich", 0.0, AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]], 
    UNIT["degree", 0.017453292519943295], 
    AXIS["Geodetic longitude", EAST], 
    AXIS["Geodetic latitude", NORTH], 
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]], 
  PROJECTION["Popular Visualisation Pseudo Mercator", AUTHORITY["EPSG","1024"]], 
  PARAMETER["semi_minor", 6378137.0], 
  PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin", 0.0], 
  PARAMETER["central_meridian", 0.0], 
  PARAMETER["scale_factor", 1.0], 
  PARAMETER["false_easting", 0.0], 
  PARAMETER["false_northing", 0.0], 
  UNIT["m", 1.0], 
  AXIS["Easting", EAST], 
  AXIS["Northing", NORTH], 
  AUTHORITY["EPSG","3857"]]
    Bbox = SRSEnvelope[240952.01878380912 : 241018.15472820433, 5070235.180186812 : 5070300.94290353]
    RemoteOwsType = null
    RemoteOwsURL = null
    Env = {}
    FormatOptions = {}
    Angle = 0.0
    CQLFilter = [[ floor = 35 ]]
    Elevation = []
    FeatureId = null
    StartIndex = null
    ViewParams = null
    Layers = [org.geoserver.wms.MapLayerInfo@be6cfff]
    Tiled = false
    Palette = null
    SRS = EPSG:3857
    FeatureVersion = null
    Styles = [StyleImpl[ name=heatmap]]
    BgColor = java.awt.Color[r=255,g=255,b=255]
    Transparent = true
    StyleFormat = sld
    SldBody = null
    ValidateSchema = false
    Sld = null
    StyleUrl = null
    TilesOrigin = null
    Interpolations = []
    Exceptions = SE_XML
    StyleBody = null
    SldVersion = null
    StyleVersion = null
    ScaleMethod = null
    Buffer = 0
    Time = [[Wed Jul 16 18:00:00 CEST 2014, Sun Jul 17 01:59:59 CEST 2016]]
    Filter = [[ floor = 35 ]]
    Format = image/png
    Filters = [[ floor = 35 ]]
    Get = true
    RawKvp = {TIME=2014-07-16T16:00:00.000Z/2016-07-16, BBOX=240952.01878380912,5070235.180186812,241018.15472820433,5070300.94290353, SERVICE=WMS, TILED=false, HEIGHT=1762, REQUEST=GetMap, STYLES=, WIDTH=1772, CQL_FILTER=floor=35, TRANSPARENT=true, VERSION=1.1.1, FORMAT=image/png, LAYERS=openrtls:presence, SRS=EPSG:3857}
    BaseUrl = http://192.168.11.50:8080/geoserver/
    RequestCharset = UTF-8
    Version = 1.1.1
    Request = GetMap
2015-10-15 10:09:10,507 ERROR [geoserver.ows] - 
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.media.jai.util.SunCachedTile.(SunCachedTile.java:80)
    at com.sun.media.jai.util.SunTileCache.add(SunTileCache.java:257)
    at javax.media.jai.OpImage.addTileToCache(OpImage.java:1087)
    at javax.media.jai.OpImage.getTile(OpImage.java:1142)
    at javax.media.jai.PlanarImage.getData(PlanarImage.java:2085)
    at javax.media.jai.PlanarImage.getData(PlanarImage.java:2016)
    at javax.media.jai.RenderedOp.getData(RenderedOp.java:2266)
    at it.geosolutions.imageio.plugins.png.ScanlineProviderFactory.getProvider(ScanlineProviderFactory.java:53)
    at it.geosolutions.imageio.plugins.png.PNGWriter.isScanlineSupported(PNGWriter.java:111)
    at org.geoserver.wms.map.png.PNGJWriter.writePNG(PNGJWriter.java:42)
    at org.geoserver.wms.map.PNGMapResponse.formatImageOutputStream(PNGMapResponse.java:109)
    at org.geoserver.wms.map.RenderedImageMapResponse.write(RenderedImageMapResponse.java:123)
    at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.response(Dispatcher.java:990)
    at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.handleRequestInternal(Dispatcher.java:284)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:153)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.geoserver.filters.ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.doFilter(ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.java:28)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:75)
    at org.geoserver.wms.animate.AnimatorFilter.doFilter(AnimatorFilter.java:71)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:71)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:46)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter.doFilter(AdvancedDispatchFilter.java:50)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:311)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.java:83)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:53)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:173)
    at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.java:135)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.geoserver.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.geoserver.filters.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:42)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SessionDebugFilter.doFilter(SessionDebugFilter.java:48)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.geoserver.filters.FlushSafeFilter.doFilter(FlushSafeFilter.java:44)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.vfny.geoserver.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I threw away three days playing with this. I decided to ask for help here and then I found the solution. Sorry for the trouble, hopefully this helps someone else.

The what:
As suspected it had to do with memory issues. The machine had enough (8GB), Geoserver has a high enough limit (1GB) but Tomcat7 had a limit of 128MB. I increased it to 1GB and then it worked as expected all the time.

The how:
I edited the file `/etc/default/tomcat7`, changed the max heap size to 1024MB and set the initial heap size to 128MB.

Original line:
`JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx128m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC"`

New line:
`JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Xms128m -Xmx1024m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC"`