# GeoServer downloads OpenLayers previews (WMS files) instead of opening GUI

Tags: geoserver

I'm posting again because I'm still stuck. The exact steps I'm taking: install Debian Stable, Java 11, Tomcat9, Nginx. Put .war file in /var/lib/tomcat9/webapps. At that point the web interface opens fine and I can log in. Run Certbot, put https://domain.com/geoserver in proxy base URL and check box below. Whitelist domain in /etc/profile (CSRF instructions). I log in fine with https but have the problem in the title. The files say

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><!DOCTYPE ServiceExceptionReport SYSTEM "https://daniellinux.com/geoserver/schemas/wms/1.1.1/WMS_exception_1_1_1.dtd"> <ServiceExceptionReport version="1.1.1" >   <ServiceException>
      java.lang.NullPointerException
</ServiceException></ServiceExceptionReport>
```

[This](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/166607/220394) didn't help.

geoserver.log:

```
30 Mar 19:25:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found System environment variable : 'org.geoserver.service.disabled' to be unset
30 Mar 19:25:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Property override: 'org.geoserver.service.disabled' to be unset
30 Mar 19:25:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Java environment variable : 'org.geoserver.service.disabled' to be unset
30 Mar 19:25:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Servlet context parameter : 'org.geoserver.service.disabled' to be unset
30 Mar 19:25:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found System environment variable : 'org.geoserver.service.disabled' to be unset
30 Mar 19:25:34 INFO   [geoserver.wms] -
Request: getServiceInfo
30 Mar 19:25:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Property override: 'org.geoserver.service.disabled' to be unset
30 Mar 19:25:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Java environment variable : 'org.geoserver.service.disabled' to be unset
30 Mar 19:25:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Servlet context parameter : 'org.geoserver.service.disabled' to be unset
30 Mar 19:25:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found System environment variable : 'org.geoserver.service.disabled' to be unset
30 Mar 19:25:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Property override: 'org.geoserver.service.disabled' to be unset
30 Mar 19:25:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Java environment variable : 'org.geoserver.service.disabled' to be unset
30 Mar 19:25:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Servlet context parameter : 'org.geoserver.service.disabled' to be unset
30 Mar 19:25:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found System environment variable : 'org.geoserver.service.disabled' to be unset
30 Mar 19:25:34 DEBUG  [geoserver.ows] - Getting layers and styles from LAYERS and STYLES
30 Mar 19:25:34 DEBUG  [geoserver.ows] - establishing populated_places style for populated_places
30 Mar 19:25:34 DEBUG  [geoserver.wms] - setting up map
30 Mar 19:25:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Property override: 'ENABLE_OL3' to be unset
30 Mar 19:25:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Java environment variable : 'ENABLE_OL3' to be unset
30 Mar 19:25:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Servlet context parameter : 'ENABLE_OL3' to be unset
30 Mar 19:25:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found System environment variable : 'ENABLE_OL3' to be unset
30 Mar 19:25:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Property override: 'PROXY_BASE_URL' to be unset
30 Mar 19:25:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Java environment variable : 'PROXY_BASE_URL' to be unset
30 Mar 19:25:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Servlet context parameter : 'PROXY_BASE_URL' to be unset
30 Mar 19:25:34 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found System environment variable : 'PROXY_BASE_URL' to be unset
30 Mar 19:25:34 INFO   [geoserver.wms] -
Request: getMap
        Angle = 0.0
        BaseUrl = http://127.0.0.1:8080/geoserver/
        Bbox = SRSEnvelope[-175.2205644999999 : 179.2166470999999, -41.29206799231509 : 64.14345946317033]
        BgColor = java.awt.Color[r=255,g=255,b=255]
        Buffer = 0
        Clip = null
        CQLFilter = null
        Crs = GEOGCS["WGS 84",
  DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
    SPHEROID["WGS 84", 6378137.0, 298.257223563, AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
  PRIMEM["Greenwich", 0.0, AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
  UNIT["degree", 0.017453292519943295],
  AXIS["Geodetic longitude", EAST],
  AXIS["Geodetic latitude", NORTH],
  AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
        Elevation = []
        Env = {}
        Exceptions = SE_XML
        FeatureId = null
        FeatureVersion = null
        Filter = null
        Format = application/openlayers
        FormatOptions = {}
        Get = true
        Height = 330
        Interpolations = []
        Layers = [org.geoserver.wms.MapLayerInfo@5ef2c670]
        MaxFeatures = null
        Palette = null
        RawKvp = {REQUEST=GetMap, SRS=EPSG:4326, FORMAT=application/openlayers, BBOX=-175.2205644999999,-41.29206799231509,179.2166470999999,64.14345946317033, VERSION=1.1.0, STYLES=, SERVICE=WMS, WIDTH=768, HEIGHT=330, LAYERS=ne:populated_places}
        RemoteOwsType = null
        RemoteOwsURL = null
        Request = GetMap
        RequestCharset = UTF-8
        ScaleMethod = null
        Sld = null
        SldBody = null
        SldVersion = null
        SortBy = null
        SortByArrays = null
        SRS = EPSG:4326
        StartIndex = null
        StyleBody = null
        StyleFormat = sld
        Styles = [StyleImpl[ name=populated_places]]
        StyleUrl = null
        StyleVersion = null
        Tiled = false
        TilesOrigin = null
        Time = []
        Transparent = false
        ValidateSchema = false
        Version = 1.1.0
        ViewParams = null
        Width = 768
30 Mar 19:25:34 DEBUG  [geoserver.filters] - Compressing output for mimetype: text/html; subtype=openlayers3
30 Mar 19:25:34 DEBUG  [filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1] - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
30 Mar 19:25:37 TRACE  [platform.resource] - polling contents of /var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/geoserver/data/gwc-layers
30 Mar 19:25:37 TRACE  [platform.resource] - delta computed in 270us for /var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/geoserver/data/gwc-layers
30 Mar 19:25:42 TRACE  [platform.resource] - polling contents of /var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/geoserver/data/gwc-layers
30 Mar 19:25:42 TRACE  [platform.resource] - delta computed in 266us for /var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/geoserver/data/gwc-layers
30 Mar 19:25:47 TRACE  [platform.resource] - polling contents of /var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/geoserver/data/gwc-layers
30 Mar 19:25:47 TRACE  [platform.resource] - delta computed in 248us for /var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/geoserver/data/gwc-layers
30 Mar 19:25:52 TRACE  [platform.resource] - polling contents of /var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/geoserver/data/gwc-layers
30 Mar 19:25:52 TRACE  [platform.resource] - delta computed in 289us for /var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/geoserver/data/gwc-layers
30 Mar 19:25:57 TRACE  [platform.resource] - polling contents of /var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/geoserver/data/gwc-layers
30 Mar 19:25:57 TRACE  [platform.resource] - delta computed in 269us for /var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/geoserver/data/gwc-layers
30 Mar 19:26:02 TRACE  [platform.resource] - polling contents of /var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/geoserver/data/gwc-layers
30 Mar 19:26:02 TRACE  [platform.resource] - delta computed in 257us for /var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/geoserver/data/gwc-layers
30 Mar 19:26:07 TRACE  [platform.resource] - polling contents of /var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/geoserver/data/gwc-layers
30 Mar 19:26:07 TRACE  [platform.resource] - delta computed in 250us for /var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/geoserver/data/gwc-layers
```

localhost.log (from /var/lib/tomcat9/logs):

```
30-Mar-2023 08:37:54.125 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
30-Mar-2023 08:37:55.129 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
30-Mar-2023 08:39:48.815 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcher'
```

catalina.log:

```
30-Mar-2023 08:37:48.991 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version name:   Apache Tomcat/9.0.43 (Debian)
30-Mar-2023 08:37:48.992 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Jan 8 1970 01:02:06 UTC
30-Mar-2023 08:37:48.992 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version number: 9.0.43.0
30-Mar-2023 08:37:48.992 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Linux
30-Mar-2023 08:37:48.992 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            5.10.0-21-amd64
30-Mar-2023 08:37:48.992 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
30-Mar-2023 08:37:48.992 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
30-Mar-2023 08:37:48.992 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           11.0.18+10-post-Debian-1deb11u1
30-Mar-2023 08:37:48.992 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Debian
30-Mar-2023 08:37:48.992 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         /var/lib/tomcat9
30-Mar-2023 08:37:48.992 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         /usr/share/tomcat9
30-Mar-2023 08:37:49.003 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
30-Mar-2023 08:37:49.003 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED
30-Mar-2023 08:37:49.003 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED
30-Mar-2023 08:37:49.003 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED
30-Mar-2023 08:37:49.004 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
30-Mar-2023 08:37:49.004 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/var/lib/tomcat9/conf/logging.properties
30-Mar-2023 08:37:49.004 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
30-Mar-2023 08:37:49.004 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.awt.headless=true
30-Mar-2023 08:37:49.004 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Xms128m
30-Mar-2023 08:37:49.004 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Xmx2048m
30-Mar-2023 08:37:49.004 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
30-Mar-2023 08:37:49.004 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
30-Mar-2023 08:37:49.004 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
30-Mar-2023 08:37:49.005 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dorg.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener.UMASK=0027
30-Mar-2023 08:37:49.005 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dignore.endorsed.dirs=
30-Mar-2023 08:37:49.005 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/var/lib/tomcat9
30-Mar-2023 08:37:49.005 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/usr/share/tomcat9
30-Mar-2023 08:37:49.005 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp
30-Mar-2023 08:37:49.008 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent Loaded Apache Tomcat Native library [1.2.26] using APR version [1.7.0].
30-Mar-2023 08:37:49.008 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
30-Mar-2023 08:37:49.009 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR/OpenSSL configuration: useAprConnector [false], useOpenSSL [true]
30-Mar-2023 08:37:49.010 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.initializeSSL OpenSSL successfully initialized [OpenSSL 1.1.1n  15 Mar 2022]
30-Mar-2023 08:37:49.222 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
30-Mar-2023 08:37:49.243 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Server initialization in [397] milliseconds
30-Mar-2023 08:37:49.295 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
30-Mar-2023 08:37:49.296 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.43 (Debian)]
30-Mar-2023 08:37:49.307 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive [/var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/geoserver.war]
30-Mar-2023 08:37:54.123 INFO [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
30-Mar-2023 08:38:01.453 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [/var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/geoserver.war] has finished in [12,146] ms
30-Mar-2023 08:38:01.454 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/ROOT]
30-Mar-2023 08:38:01.800 INFO [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
30-Mar-2023 08:38:01.802 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/ROOT] has finished in [348] ms
30-Mar-2023 08:38:01.802 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/license]
30-Mar-2023 08:38:02.126 INFO [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
30-Mar-2023 08:38:02.129 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/license] has finished in [327] ms
30-Mar-2023 08:38:02.129 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/target]
30-Mar-2023 08:38:02.451 INFO [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
30-Mar-2023 08:38:02.453 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/target] has finished in [324] ms
30-Mar-2023 08:38:02.456 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
30-Mar-2023 08:38:02.462 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in [13218] milliseconds
30-Mar-2023 08:41:47.141 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-6] java.util.prefs.FileSystemPreferences$1.run Couldn't create user preferences directory. User preferences are unusable.
30-Mar-2023 08:41:47.142 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-6] java.util.prefs.FileSystemPreferences$1.run java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
```

Comment: That's not downloading a preview file.  It's downloading an error message (within an XML file) returned by a WMS service.  The actual error message is:  `java.lang.NullPointerException`.  You may need to check the Geoserver logs to find out what's going wrong.

Comment: Can you find from the Nginx or Tomcat logs what request is coming in?

Comment: You need to turn up the logging level to developer in the global settings page, and then make the request again. Then [edit] your question with the **relevant** part of the log file.

Comment: Edited. I don't think a log file is even being created, assuming geoserver.log is in the directory I mentioned.

Comment: I stopped Nginx, made the changes, restarted it and now all of a sudden everything's working, no clue why. Dev logging's on but still see no logs.

Comment: I found the logs. Same problem (last six previews don't load) and also when I try adding a workspace I get a 400.